An Inequality in Operator Theory
This theorem is taken from Linear Operators in Hilbert Spaces by Joachim Weidmann.
Let $T$ be a densely defined operator on a complex pre-Hilbert space, or a symmetric operator defined on an arbitrary pre-Hilbert space. $T$ is bounded if and only if
$$
C = \sup \{ |\langle f, Tf \rangle| : f \in \mathcal{D}(T), \|f\| \leq 1 \} < \infty.
$$
If $T$ is bounded, then we have
a) $$\lVert T \rVert \leq 2C, \text{if $H$ is a complex Hilbert space}$$
b) $$\lVert T \rVert = C,  \text{if $T$ is symmetric}$$
in the proof, there is an inequality that I didn't get. It seemed to be used multiple times as well.
It is: Given $\|f\|, \|g\| \leq 1$, we have
$$\frac{1}{4} C \left\{ \|f + g\|^2 + \|f - g\|^2 + \|f + ig\|^2 + \|f - ig\|^2 \right\} \geq \frac{1}{4} \left| \langle f + g, T(f + g) \rangle - \langle f - g, T(f - g) \rangle - i \langle f + ig, T(f + ig) \rangle + i \langle f - ig, T(f - ig) \rangle \right|
  $$
Like, I tried to make it make sense, but I got stumped since $\|f+g\|$ isn't necessarily less than 1.
Just additional context: In the book, the inner product is written backwards. So, $\langle g, Tf \rangle$ in this book means $\langle Tf, g \rangle$.

By scaling we have $ \langle f, Tf \rangle \le C|f|^{2}$ for any  $f$. Just note that $|(f/|f|)|= 1$ and $f/|f| \in D(T)$.
